# I want to restrict the user to like my facebook page before any download?

Tags: wordpress

I want that the user who ever visits the site should first like the facebook page and then only he is allowed to download any stuff from the website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many plugins that have this (or similar) features which you could use out-of-the-box or look at the code to see how it is done .
Some use Tweeter, Some facebook, Some e-mails and some all of the above . essentially they are all the same .
A simple [SEARCH](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=Like%20%20to%20%20download&sort=) in the [plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php) reveals some candidates :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/like-gate/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-share-to-unlock/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tweet-and-get-it/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tweet2download/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/email-before-download/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i also found a javascript for that and guess what that worked

Comment: good. now you might want to either accept this answer or to post your own answer with explanation and accept it as to mark this question as closed .